# Is there a way to create custom postfix completions in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to be able to make custom postfix completions, but I can't seem to find anywhere to do so and haven't been able to find anything online. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 25):

Now you can.  I've written a plugin for IDEA that allows you to create your own postfix templates.  It's called [Custom Postfix Templates](https://github.com/xylo/intellij-postfix-templates):

[image]

Comment: Great ! But can you use global variables like with live templates ? I'd like to have access to ClassName, MethodName etc.

Comment: @DanChaltiel Yes, you can use variables and macros.  The macros are the same as in live templates.  The code completion will help you with the macro names.  Note that some macros require arguments (same as in live templates).

Comment: I tried `$CLASS_NAME_CHAR$`, `$METHOD_NAME$` and `$LINE_NUMBER$` but with no result (though it's working in live templates). The code completion only hints me to `$END$` which is also empty and `$expr$` which acts as expeted. Where should I look for variables names ?

Comment: (if you want some context, I'd like to add this : `java.lang.Object  → 
 android.util.Log.d("MyTag", "$CLASS_NAME_CHAR$ :: $METHOD_NAME$ ($LINE_NUMBER$): $expr$="+$expr$);`)

Comment: $CLASS_NAME_CHAR$, $METHOD_NAME$ and $LINE_NUMBER$ are just normal variables, also in live templates.  If they are mapped to special values such as class names or method names, then this is done using macros (also in live templates).  If you tell me in which live template you've found those variables I can help you with the macro names and with the postfix template.  Anyway, this is getting lengthy here, so I suggest to discuss this in a new thread: https://github.com/xylo/intellij-postfix-templates/issues/40

Answer (score 11):

You can't. 
Well, postfix feature is basically Postfix Plugin for IntelliJ(now integrated). All templates are just compiled code, as you can see here:

https://github.com/controlflow/intellij-postfix/tree/master/src/org/jetbrains/postfixCompletion/templates

Sadly, there isn't such easy xml like configuration. :(

Comment: I created a feature request for adding support for custom postfix templates: https://github.com/controlflow/intellij-postfix/issues/19

Comment: Please upvote if you care: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122443

Answer (score 9):

With the latest release i.e IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1, you can. That too, without using any plugin. It's embedded into the IDE itself.

https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/02/intellij-idea-2018-1-eap-partial-git-commits-and-more/

[image]

[image]

Comment: Great ! But what about using variables like in Editor>Live Templates ? I'd like to have the className auto filled...

Comment: @DanChaltiel If you want to use macros such as `className` use the *Custom Postfix Templates* plugin.