# Set "new" as a postfix completion in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I would like to set `new` postfix completion in Intellij:

```
// Type .new at the end of some class
Random.new
```

Pressing `tab` should generate

```
Random random = new Random();
```

I tried the following live template:

```
// expectedType() as an expression for $TYPE$
// suggestVariableName() as an expression for $VAR$
$TYPE$ $VAR$ = new $TYPE$();
```

but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't create custom postfix completions in IntelliJ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29248188/is-there-a-way-to-create-custom-postfix-completions-in-intellij

Comment: @DarekKay Yeah, I noticed, but I hope that someone has done the required behaviour with live template.

Comment: I think your edit shouldn't be a part of a question, but an answer.

Comment: @Rumid Done :).

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

- https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9862-custom-postfix-templates. This actually already have a configuration for `new` postfix completion.
- IntelliJ 2018.1 has integrated support https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#v2018-1